# Brackets live preview not working

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I am working on a local project (read: offline) and I am trying to get Brackets' live preview to work since it comes in handy quite often.

Right now I have opened my project files using Brackets' "open file" option since it supposedly maps the path to the source files. Although I am getting an error saying `In order for Live Preview to connect, Chrome needs to be relaunched with remote debugging enabled`.

I have read else where that Chrome, by default, does not need to be relaunched for that change and that Brackets force this flag by itself.

I have tried reinstalling Brackets, launching with another project and searched all over Chrome for this flag and did not find any thing.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) shows you how to instal remote debugging! It's a Chrome dev tool. It's geared towards android apps for whatever reason, but I had that same error, and following the instructions on that page helped me launch the brackets page.

If that doesn't work, here are some troubleshooting tips that have helped me out with live preview:

1) Make sure your filename has a .html at the end 
2) Use different browser (I've found chrome to be a bit finicky with brackets)
3) Make a different blank file, launch that, then launch the file

Answer (score 1):

Click File -> Enable Experimental Live Preview.

Source: https://www.allbloggertricks.com/2020/04/fixed-brackets-live-preview-chrome-relaunched-error.html

Comment: This works!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Open the folder, not the file, and then select the file.